# extract values from an ArrayList of Hashmap with java8

Tags: java, arraylist, hashmap, java-8, java-stream

i have an arrayList of HashMap

how can i do with java 8 and .map .filter techniques to get an ArrayList of String of some value in the HashMap

for exemple

String data equals to

```
[{
    "schema": [{
        "name": "#VALUE",
        "dataType": {},
        "nullable": true,
        "metadata": {
            "map": {}
        }
    }, {
        "name": "@ref",
        "dataType": {},
        "nullable": true,
        "metadata": {
            "map": {}
        }
    }],
    "values": [null, 442256]
}, {
    "schema": [{
        "name": "#VALUE",
        "dataType": {},
        "nullable": true,
        "metadata": {
            "map": {}
        }
    }, {
        "name": "@ref",
        "dataType": {},
        "nullable": true,
        "metadata": {
            "map": {}
        }
    }],
    "values": [null, 4192463331]
}, {
    "schema": [{
        "name": "#VALUE",
        "dataType": {},
        "nullable": true,
        "metadata": {
            "map": {}
        }
    }, {
        "name": "@ref",
        "dataType": {},
        "nullable": true,
        "metadata": {
            "map": {}
        }
    }],
    "values": [null, 34817060]
}, {
    "schema": [{
        "name": "#VALUE",
        "dataType": {},
        "nullable": true,
        "metadata": {
            "map": {}
        }
    }, {
        "name": "@ref",
        "dataType": {},
        "nullable": true,
        "metadata": {
            "map": {}
        }
    }],
    "values": [null, 291594905]
}]
```

the result

```
["442256","4192463331","34817060","291594905"]
```

this part of my code but not working

```
    Stream.of(mapper.readValue(mapper.writeValueAsString(data),ArrayList.class))
            .filter(c -> c instanceof ArrayList<?>)
            .map(ArrayList.class::cast)
            .map(c -> 
                    c.forEach(f -> { Stream.of(mapper.readValue(mapper.writeValueAsString(f),HashMap.class))
                                    .filter(f -> f instanceof HashMap<?,?>)
                                    .map(HashMap.class::cast)
                                    ...
                                }
                            )
                )
            .forEach(System.out::println);
```

any idea?

cordially

Comment: You did not provide a [MCVE](http://www.stackoverflow.com)

Comment: Please post an entire runnable code.

Comment: First, create a `List<Map<String, List<Object>>>`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The code in your question is quite confusing but if I take the question itself literally you are asking, "given a `List<Map<String, String>>` how do I get a `List<String>` representing all values in the maps for a given key?" If that is actually your question in spite of not matching your code, then here is an answer:

```
List<Map<String, String>> listOfMaps;
List<String> valuesMatchingKey = listOfMaps.stream()
    .filter(map -> map.containsKey("Key"))
    .map(map -> map.get("Key"))
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: List<HashMap<String,ArrayList<String>>> listOfMaps = mapper.readValue(mapper.writeValueAsString(data),ArrayList.class);  
  List<String> valuesMatchingKey = listOfMaps.stream()
      .filter(map -> map.containsKey("values"))
      .map(map -> String.valueOf(
          map.get("values").get(1)
         )
      )
      .collect(Collectors.toList());

thank you it works for me